# Servlet: proper way to redirect to index versus show view in doGet() method

Tags: servlets

Given this `doGet` implementation:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    if (request.getParameterMap().isEmpty()) {

        // DAO initialized in init() method
        Collection<User> users = resource.getUsers();

        if (users != null){

            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("users", users);

        }

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/users/index.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }

    else {

        String name = request.getParameter("name");

        // DAO initialized in init() method
        User user = resource.getUser(name);

        if (user == null){
            request.setAttribute("message", "Unknown user: " + name);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/errors/404.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }

        else {

            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("user", user);

            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/users/show.jsp").forward(request, response);

        }

    }

}
```

Questions:

1. Is `request.getParameterMap().isEmpty()` the preferred way to test for the presence of parameters?
2. Is there a way to infer the views' location (/WEB-INF/users/) from the either the Servlet's context or an annotation?

Answer (score 0):

> *Is `request.getParameterMap().isEmpty()` the preferred way to test for the presence of parameters?*

Yes, it is. But this is not the right solution for *your particular case*. Your code will fail if the enduser supplied an arbitrary parameter with other name than `name`, causing the parameter map to be not empty and thus enter the block which expects the `name` parameter. You should really explicitly check the request parameter `name` itself.

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");

if (name == null) {
    Collection<User> users = resource.getUsers();
    // ...
}
else {
    User user = resource.getUser(name);
    // ...
}
```

---

> *Is there a way to infer the views' location (`/WEB-INF/users/`) from the either the Servlet's context or an annotation?*

Use a MVC framework (recommended) or [homebrew one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/) (not recommended, unless 100% internal/private/hobby and thus for pure learning purposes).